# How to open .pmd and .ocd files using python?

Tags: python-3.x, telecommunication

I'm working on my own fiber optic analysis software. Nevertheless, I'm facing a challenge in opening files about Polarization Mode Dispersion (.pmd) and Chromatic Dispersion (.ocd). OTDR curves (.sor) I'm opening it just fine using pyOTDR. SOR files I know that they are built based on the definitions of standard Telcordia SR-4731. But about .pmd and .ocd I know nothing about standards that defines their constructions. Does anyone have a suggestion about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is pretty much that, the lack of code. I have files but I don't know how to extract the information from them. I would like to know if anyone has the slightest idea of where to begin in order to extract the information